# Do the Gauss–Codazzi–Mainardi equations imply isometric immersibility?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I have a two-manifold homeomorphic to the disk, and I prescribe a first and second fundamental form $a$ and $b$, and that these forms are compatible, in the sense of satisfying the Gauss-Codazzi-Mainardi equations.

It is well-known that the manifold may not be isometrically immersible in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for *any* $b$. So let's suppose also that the manifold has at least one isometric immersion. Must one of these immersions have second fundamental form $b$?

Comment: I'm confused. In the case you cite, there is no $b$ satisfying the integrability conditions. If you in fact have an $a$ and $b$ satisfying the compatibility conditions, then you're golden. So is your question really just for what $a$ there exists an isometric immersion?

Comment: @TedShifrin I give you two tensor fields $a$, $b$ on an abstract two-manifold, and these tensor fields satisfy the compatibility equations. Does there then exist an immersion of the manifold whose first fundamental form is $a$ and whose second is $b$? Or are you saying that the compatibility conditions are enough to guarantee I can "integrate up" the immersion given the tensor fields?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that the Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory (proved first by Bonnet) says precisely that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Great, thanks. If you post an answer with a reference, I'll upvote and accept it (otherwise I'll answer myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory says precisely that, given symmetric bilinear forms $a$ and $b$, the Gauss and Mainardi-Codazzi equations are precisely the integrability conditions to obtain an immersed surface in $\Bbb R^3$ (on a simply connected domain). In fact, it holds more generally for hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

See, for example, Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, Volume 3, pp. 56-59, or Kobayashi-Nomizu, *Foundations of Differential Geometry*, Volume 2, pp. 47-51. One can also prove it, in differential forms version, as an application of the Frobenius Theorem. For this, see Chern, Chen, Lam, *Lectures on Differential Geometry*, Section 6.3.